# Does i3-2100t stock cooler have preapplied thermal pad?

Tags: cpu, heatsink

This might be a dumb question, but I'm currently building an HTPC and am a bit oversensitive about my components!  I'm using a intel core i3-2100t processor and I just want to make sure that I don't need to apply any thermal paste with the stock cooler.  Underneath the cooler, I do see 3 grey strips.  The intel manual doesn't mention anything, but my MOBO manual does.  I know the processor runs cool, but I want to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most consumer processors currently in the market come with thermal paste pre-applied on the stock cooler. So the answer to your question is yes.